# Different file owner inside Docker container and in host machine

Tags: linux, docker, devops

I am facing a issue related to Docker users.
I run my container as `gitlab-runner` using the following command:

```
docker run --name testes_cashlink --hostname testes_cashlink --user gitlab-runner --privileged -t -v $DIR_TESTES:/cashlink_host -v $DIR_BATS:/bats -v $DIR_PROJETO:/cashlink_war docker-cashlink-ci /bats/run.sh
```

The files created inside the docker container show owner `gitlab-runner`, however, the same files show in my host machine as owner `roggerfernandes`. `gitlab-runner` must be the owner of files created inside Docker container as well as host machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filesystems, at least in Unix- and Linux-like systems (including macOS), file owners are a number, not a name. Various tools such as `ls` will translate the number into a name for convenience, but it is still just a number. Your user `gitlab-runner` in the container, and the user `roggerfernandes` on the host system, have the same UID. You can find the numeric ID by running the `id` command.

Here it is on my laptop (reformatted a bit for readability):

```
$ id
uid=501(dan) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),
  79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),501(access_bpf),
  33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),395(com.apple.access_ftp),
  398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh)
```

Here you see at the beginning my UID is 501.

You can also run this command with a username, e.g. `id gitlab-runner` inside the container.

```
docker exec testes_cashlink id gitlab-runner
```

So when the user in the container owns a file, it is stored as a numeric ID (quite likely 1000, a common default). When you look on your host system, the mechanism that translates the number into a username just has a different username in its result than you would see inside the container.

If you need a specific user ID inside the container, you need to modify your Dockerfile so that when creating the user, you specify its uid. For example:

```
RUN useradd -u 1005 <other options> gitlab-runner
```