# mongodb data directory owned by influxdb:root when dockerizing mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have no idea why the directory is created by influxdb user. This is on ubuntu 18.04

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 8700
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
#VOLUME /data/db /data/configdb
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    container_name: puump-api
    restart: always
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "8700:3000"
    links:
      - mongo
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    networks:
      - puump-network
  mongo:
    container_name: puump-mongo
    image:  mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "28017:27017"
    networks:
      - puump-network
networks:
  puump-network:
    driver: bridge
```

`drwxr-xr-x   4 influxdb root       4096 Sep 21 08:13 mongo-data`

Comment: It should be not influxdb user if you are using offical image. as offical image contain default user `mongodb`. double check and verify which container is based on influx db

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: run `docker ps` and check the container which image is being used. and verify you incorrect container.  
mongo will never up if the directory owned by another user. just change the running container permission and mongo container will break  `chown -R root db/`

Comment: Oh got it. i thought you talking about the inside container directory. posting answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different file owner inside Docker container and in host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624758/different-file-owner-inside-docker-container-and-in-host-machine)

Comment: Whatever non-zero _numeric_ user ID the `mongo` image uses for itself, your host's `/etc/passwd` file maps it to that username.  This isn't usually a problem.

Answer (score 0):

`mongo-data` is the host directory so you seeing the directory permission from Host the side so it does not matter which user the host directory unless docker has access to bind the directory.

So it might be the case the host user is root or influx.

To verify the correct permission you need to check inside mongo container and it should be owned by `mongodb` user.

```
docker exec -it puump-mongo bash -c "ls -ltrah /data/"
```

So the `/data/db` should be owned by `mongodb` user if the image is offical.

Comment: `Error: No such container: mongocompose_mongo_1`

Comment: fixed. your container name is `puump-mongo`

Comment: ```$ docker exec -it puump-mongo bash -c "ls -ltrah /data/"
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Sep 19 01:12 configdb
drwxr-xr-x 4 root    root    4.0K Sep 19 01:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root    4.0K Sep 21 15:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 mongodb root    4.0K Sep 21 16:00 db```

Comment: so you can see the correct permission that is mongodb

Comment: yes. but the volume on the host is owned by `influxdb:root`. Its a brand new directory too in the current project dir. If I delete it and run `docker-compose up` again it re-creates it with same perms.

Comment: it is fine, as container manage it internal permission, host file and folder can own any user. so you can change the host permission

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199771/discussion-between-adiii-and-chovy).

Comment: This still doesn't work. Everytime I deploy it recreates the directory with wrong permissions.

Comment: As mentioned by David it's take the Id of your existing user, check the list of user there should influxdb users in the list on your host

Comment: on the server it gets owned by 999

Comment: The id of influxdb would be 999

Comment: I think there is no thing wrong the permission, if the concept is clear now and the reason behind

Comment: How do I create a volume owned by my host user "ubuntu"? docker-compose doens't have a --user flag.

Comment: for that you might need to add this dockerfile `RUN groupadd -r mongodb && useradd -u <your_ubuntu_user_id> -r -g mongodb mongodb`

Comment: you need to build from the scrach https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/2f757af6d12f4239cf5541455b011921ee4c06d1/4.2/Dockerfile