# How to change user of docker service?

Tags: linux, docker, system-administration

I'm having problem because i've installed & started docker as a "bad_user". The problem is that this container generates static files (its jekyll/jekyll image), and those files are owned by "bad_user" so i cannot edit them (i know i could add myself to bad_user group or own the dir by chown -R but it would be painful to do every time, and it just bugs me :).

I have tried to reinstall docker & removing /etc/docker directory without any effect. Every time i reinstall it (docker service/manager) runs as "bad_user" and overwrites directory owner.

My question is:
**Would that be possible to make docker running under "docker" user ? I have already created that user with that group (yes, i have reinstalled docker-ce under that user already).**

Im working on debian-based distro.

I guess in my case its docker daemon issue, somehow when its syncrhonizing shared volume files it gives permission to bad_user instead of user who is running container.

PS. This is the command i run if that matters:

```
docker run --rm -p 8000:8000 \
  --volume="/home/docker/blog:/srv/jekyll" \
  -it tocttou/jekyll:3.5 \
  jekyll serve --watch --port 8000
```

Comment: Can you share your `docker run` command?  In particular, is your issue that you're using `docker run -v` to share a host directory with the container, and they're showing up owned by `bad_user` on the host when you do `ls -l`?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thats the command:
docker run --rm -p 8000:8000 \
  --volume="/home/docker/blog:/srv/jekyll" \
  -it tocttou/jekyll:3.5 \
  jekyll serve --watch --port 8000

Before starting command i own blog dir (docker user owns it) after generating some files in it the bad_user owns it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different file owner inside Docker container and in host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624758/different-file-owner-inside-docker-container-and-in-host-machine)

Comment: The container process runs with some _numeric_ user ID; it doesn't know anything about the user names on the host, or what user might have launched the container.  The answer to the above question discusses this a little further.

Comment: @DavidMaze So as far as i understand docker inside container most likely uses uid=1000 so my host translated this into my "bad_user" when i executed 'ls -l'. I guess that might be the case. I'll check that later on when i get home. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i figured it out. It turns out that when you run linux container that creates some files on the shared volume (the -v argument makes shared volume), the file permissions will be for user with grup id = 1000 and id = 1000. In my case user with id=1000 was "bad_user". If you want to workaround that you can use --user and specify user id that you're running under.
The key is to remember that linux permissions are just numbers, for host filesystem number 1000 is (in my case) "bad_user" and 10001 is "docker_user". If you check permissions from inside of the container you'll might see that user id = 1000 means very different user than on your host system.

I hope that next people who will encounter this issue will find that userful.

You can find more information here: https://dille.name/blog/2018/07/16/handling-file-permissions-when-writing-to-volumes-from-docker-containers/